# Variance in the number of dice throws required to attain a fixed sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I repeatedly perform (fair, independent) throws of 6-sided dice and stop as soon as the sum of all throws recorded so far exceeds a constant $c$ (say, 100). I'm interested in the number of throws I will wind up performing (let's say this is an RV $Y_c$). I figure that the *expectation* of $Y_c$ is probably something straightforward by Wald's equation, but what is its *variance*/second moment/$\mathbb{E}[Y_c^2]-\mathbb{E}[Y_c]^2$?

The problem I'm actually trying to solve is more convoluted and this is a toy version, so I'm especially interested in any general statements about the second moment of the corresponding random variable $Y_c=\inf \{n:\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq c\}$ for partial sums of sequences of independent (not necessarily identically distributed) random variables $\{X_i\}$; if there is nothing obvious of the sort, though, I'm quite happy if I can just get some inspiration for techniques that may work.

Comment: Do we know anything at all about the $X_i$? Are they discrete? Non-negative? Integer-valued?

Comment: Non-negative and integer-valued (though I don't see how the latter should matter). You may also assume that $\mathrm{Var}(X_n) = O(\mathbb{E}[X_n]^2)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_n) = 2^{o(n)}$.